Python requests module: Failed to resolve 'domain' ([Errno -3]
In my project I am sending a request to a specific API from a route (Flask app)
When running the code in the development server, all works well, but when running from a docker container using gunicorn, the request fail with the following error:
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ana.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /hidrowebservice/EstacoesTelemetricas/OAUth/v1 (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f69d27a6a50>: Failed to resolve 'ana.gov.br' ([Errno -3] Lookup timed out)"))

The following route generates the error:
@observatorioBp.route("/teste")
def teste():
    url_ana_login = r"https://ana.gov.br/hidrowebservice/EstacoesTelemetricas/OAUth/v1"
    response = requests.get(
        url_ana_login,
        headers={
            "identificador": IDENTIFICATOR_API_ANA,
            "senha": PASSWORD_API_ANA,
        },
    )

    return response.json()

when running the same request from a iterative shell inside the container the request sucessed.
I am obviously missing a point here, but can't figure it out.
Trying to determine the origin of the erroer, i tried to reach others APIs and the same error occours.
ps: Sorry for the poorly written english, it is not my first language.

Sounds like a network configuration issue with your container rather than a problem in your code.

Do you have this problem with other urls? how did you configure docker? Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

@furas the code fails exactly on
        url_ana_login,
        headers={
            "identificador": IDENTIFICATOR_API_ANA,
            "senha": PASSWORD_API_ANA,
        },
    )

and I started the container with:
´docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -p 5000:5000 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 my_test
mainly as a way to make sure the container has access to any resource it needs to complete the request

you should put all these information in question. It will be more readable, and more people may see it - so more people may help you.
